# Does a question mark (?) come to the end of a sentence which starts with "How to ..." ? if no/yes why?

Tags: questions, question-mark

Do these sentences need question mark?

How To Repair and Restore Windows 10   (?)

Or

How to fix java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/beans/Introspector error     (?)

(this is a programming question)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question marks in titles, in particular those beginning 'How to ...'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/457180/question-marks-in-titles-in-particular-those-beginning-how-to) Obviously, the present question doesn't specify 'titles', but fragments such as 'How to R/repair Phakoship[?]' are usually titles and always classifiable with titles.

Comment: thx , you r right , that solved my problem @Edwin

Comment: That's good, tahaGhSa. And welcome to ELU. There's an awful lot of stuff here (often helpful!), but some of it is only easily retrievable by people who're (1) immensely old and have used the site for years, and (2) nerdish. But I'm allowed out sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on the intent.

If you are actually asking that question, then the mark should appear.

> How to restore Windows 10?

If you mean to relay a fact (or statement), you essentially mean to tell the person something. Give them some information to play with.
Hence, a question mark should not be required here. As such a statement would qualify as assertive or imperative. But certainly not interrogative.

> How to restore windows 10.

Read the full stop at the end of this sentence as "...is this..."